# Magento not showing homepage correctly after installation

Tags: magento2, configuration

I'm new to Magento so please forgive me if the there are not enough details.

I tried to install Magento and everything was fine.
When I go to the homepage it doesn't show the content correctly. The admin panel is not working either.

I searched for several guides but unfortunately they didn't help.

Magento version: 2.0.7; no demo store

Edit:

The pictures (Magento logo) does not show properly as well as the text is just like a list. Seems like the css part is not being showed

My solution:

I have reinstalled magento instead on apache on Nginx and it worked.

Comment: When you load the page, what errors are being kicked in the console? Looking in the `pub/static` folder, what do you see in there? Do you have the files building correctly? And what are the permission/ownership on the files in the site?

Answer (score 5):

I hope this will help you

If you are using wamp server on windows then

**`C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12>php.exe C:\wamp\www\<Magento root directory>\bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy`** 
in your  CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I would be willing to bet 1 penny that your base urls in the magento settings are not correct.  You can change them in the admin area by going to Configuration -> Web -> Base URLs. Also be sure there is a / at the end of the base urls you have entered otherwise it's wrong!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on apache with mod_php, In that case you need to fix files permissions, using the alanstorm solution http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_adding_frontend_files_to_your_module

```
find /path/to/magento2/pub/static -exec chmod 777 '{}' +
find /path/to/magento2/var/ -exec chmod 777 '{}' +
```